# remove little space left between the starting of the div and the browser border?

Tags: html, css

everytime i create a div tag and use css there is this little space between browser border and the start of the div.here is a link to what i am talking about. Any way i can remove it?
http://jsfiddle.net/Tps82/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JS Fiddle adds a padding automatically. Get rid of it like this...

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

You should also read about CSS reset stylesheets...

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

I hope this helps.
Hristo